# Passing arguments by reference in header file

Tags: c++

I have 3 files:

file1.h

```
#ifndef FILE_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdbool.h>  // To prevent unknown type 'bool' error
bool parse(char** &buffer);

#endif
```

file1.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool parse(char** &buffer) {
  buffer[0] == "test";
}
```

And file2.cpp includes file1.h and calls parse() with a char **buffer;

When compiling I get:

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before & token
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm building a project that uses raw sockets, and it's mostly C code.

Comment: *To prevent unknown type 'bool' error* ... you're probably using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler

Comment: If you are using a C++ compiler you can simplify using std::string & instead of char ** &.

Comment: What system are you running this on? What compiler? If you are using Linux, try using g++ instead of gcc to compile it.

Comment: Arch linux, I'm using gcc and if I use g++ I get undefined reference to parse(char**&)

Comment: So you randomly decided to switch compilers? No, you should have researched the cause of your "undefined reference" error instead. This way you just made things worse! Don't try to program by guessing.

Comment: May it will be better if you tell us (after you tell yourself) what exactly you want to do or achieve, and in what language.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really trying to do is to pass an array of char pointers, therefore you could change the function to

```
bool parse(char** buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler, in C language mode, is complaining about the `&` symbol:

```
bool parse(char ** &buffer)
```

The C language does not allow the `&` character in that context.

However, it is valid C++ syntax, as the function is requiring a pointer passed by reference.

As others have said, switch to a C++ compiler or tell your compiler to compiler the file as C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

This clue:

```
bool parse(char** &buffer) {
  buffer[0] == "test";
}
```

Indicates that 'buffer' is to be some sort of reference to some sort of array of strings.  Not sure why it is returning a bool (which you overlooked, anyway.)

You should consider:

```
// a std::vector of std::string
typedef  std::vector<std::string>  StrVec_t;

// parse can easily add individual std::strings 
// to the std::vector (from some unknown source)
bool parse (StrVec_t& buffer) 
{
    buffer.push_back(std::string("test"));  // tbd - where did 'test' come from?
    return(true);  // and add some meaning to this, or perhaps remove
}

// and is used as
// ...
StrVec_t  myWords;
// ...
// ...
(void)parse(myWords); // update myWords from some other source
// ...                // example of how to discard bool
```

Comment: And yes, this will require a C++ compiler.